# How to Prove or disprove the set $A=\{x\mid x=(-1)^nk,\:k\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has same cardinality as set $B=\{y:y=5n,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove the set $ A=\{x\mid x= (-1)^n k,\:k\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{N}\} $ has the same cardinality as the set $B=\{y:y=5n,\:n \in\mathbb{N}\}$.

What I think is A is actually the set of all integers and so A and B both are countable and have a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$ that's why there exists a bijection between them. I am confused if my reasoning is right or wrong?

Comment: Yes, $A = \mathbb Z$ and countably infinite as stated above, so the problem comes down to showing $B$ is countably infinite.

Comment: B is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ so it has to be countable. Isn't it enough?

Comment: Perhaps a few words about why $B$ is not finite would be enough.